# Play RTP stream withouth RTSP in Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, gstreamer, rtp

I'd like to play a RTP stream in an Android VideoView. I create the stream with gstreamer on a linux machine and fire the rtp stream to a udp sink.

Is it possible to consume this stream in an Android VideoView without having a RTSP server?

I tried to set the video URI to "rtp://:@" but then I got an error "Video could not be played". I also thought about creating an SDP file and using that on the Android device. But I'm not sure if this works and how to create such a file.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to  play RTP streams without RTSP? I am working on a similar thing.  No progress so far....please help

Comment: I am working on a similar thing. How did you deal with this issue? Below answer is not enough for me.

Comment: @Soccertrash I am currently looking for RTP playing in android device. How did you achieve the playback?

Comment: I've implemented the whole protocol on my own.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Above link is first stop for what is support or no.

As it says rtp only in conjunction with sdp as per rtsp spec.

No can't do naked rtp stream in base android.

Try porting some lib like [live555](https://github.com/boltonli/ohbee/tree/master/android/streamer/jni) if you must have naked rtp.